# Cancelling input read from io.Reader After Time Limit

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, go, io

I am wondering how to cancel an input read after a timer expires. I am currently reading from input with

```
fmt.Fscanln(reader, &var)
```

I have a channel that will be filled with a value as soon as the timer expires. I currently have the scan happening on a different go routine. This way, the function that scan's will return when it runs out of time.

The problem is if the `io.Reader` passed to `fmt.Fscanln` is reading from `stdin`, it will still wait for input after its goroutine is over. Is there a way to cancel the read if time expires?

Thanks!

Comment: There's no clean way to cancel a read from stdin. The usual way to do this is to just leave the read, and ignore any further input.

Comment: Why not use a io.ReadCloser ?

Comment: 0x434d53: there's no way to interrupt a Read on stdin, even with a Close method.