# Stopping a bufio.Scanner with a stop channel

Tags: go

I'm writing something that reads lines from `os.Stdin` using a `bufio.Scanner` like:

```
for s.scanner.Scan() {
  line := s.scanner.Text()
  // process line
}
```

This is running in a goroutine and I want to be able to stop it when a `chan struct{}` closes. However as `Scan` blocks until there is another line, I'm at a loss as how to stop it, if there is no more input, it'll block indefinitely.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: Use select, to either receive from the scanner, or receive from the channel. A read from a closed channel returns immediately. According to JimB's comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35537794/cancelling-input-read-from-io-reader-after-time-limit), there's no way to interrupt a read on stdin.

Comment: You can't use select to receive from a scanner, it doesn't expose a channel to read from. Yes I understand there is no simple/direct way to stop a blocking read, that is why I've asked the question for possible workarounds :)

Comment: Correct, thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By creating one more indirection and ignoring the underlying, we can stop.

```
// actual reading, converts input stream to a channel
func readUnderlying(lines chan interface{}) {
    s := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    for s.Scan() {
        lines <- s.Text()
    }
    lines <- s.Err()
}

func read(stop chan struct{}) {
    input := make(chan interface{}) // input stream
    go readUnderlying(input) // go and read
    for {
        select { // read or close
        case lineOrErr := <-input:
            fmt.Println(lineOrErr)
        case <-stop:
            return
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    stop := make(chan struct{})
    go read(stop)

    // wait some to simulate blocking
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 20) // it will print what is given
    close(stop)
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 20) // stopped so no more processing
}
```

Comment: I did consider this, but I didn't think leaving a dangling goroutine was the best solution. I guess it will just be blocking on `lines <- s.Text()` because nothing is reading from that goroutine any more..

Comment: @MichaelBaldry Yes, not perfect but consumes minimal resources. Depends on the situation and a simpler solution might be closing `os.Stdin` since it's a `io.Closer`.

Comment: `readUnderlying` goroutine will be killed along with main, there is no way to stop `readUnderlying` goroutine ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue (*albeit I was scanning `stdout` and `stderr`*) where I wanted to the parent caller to close those child go routines. My solution was to close the `stdout` & `stderr` pipes, which would subsequently end `Scan()` loop.

To close out the entire function, I just pass a channel call to `tearDown` from where ever I need and that would stop both children go routines (`stdoutRoutine` & `stderrRoutine`); therefore cleaning up stopping all my functions.

```
var (
    tearDown       = make(chan struct{})
    stdoutDoneChan = make(chan struct{})
    stderrDoneChan = make(chan struct{})
)

func main() {

  go runCommandThenCloseStdoutStderrPipe()

  // Send 'tearDown' channel command to close all functions after 1-second.
  // This will tear down the functions BEFORE the second set of BASH commands.
  time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)

  tearDown <- struct{}{}

  // Pad out some time to make sure main garbage collection doesn't automatically tear it down (allows code to show proof-of-concept)
  time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)
}

func runCommandThenCloseStdoutStderrPipe() {
  cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "echo Hello; echo 1>&2 World!; sleep 2; echo Closing; echo 1>&2 loop...")

  stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
  if err != nil {
      panic(err)
  }
  stderr, err := cmd.StderrPipe()
  if err != nil {
      panic(err)
  }
  if err = cmd.Start(); err != nil {
      panic(err)
  }

  defer func() {
    if err = cmd.Process.Kill(); err != nil { panic(err) }
  }()

  go stdoutRoutine(stdout)
  go stderrRoutine(stderr)

  var exitLoop bool

  for !exitLoop {
    select {

    // Channel call to tear down children routines
    case <- tearDown:
      stdout.Close()
      stderr.Close()

      // Block to ensure those children close
      <- stdoutDoneChan
      <- stderrDoneChan
      exitLoop = true
    }
  }
  fmt.Println("All functions are now closed")
}

func stdoutRoutine(stdout io.ReadCloser) {

  defer func() {
    fmt.Println("Closing stdoutRoutine")
    stdoutDoneChan <- struct{}{}
  }()

  scanner := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
  for scanner.Scan() {
    line := scanner.Text() // or whatever type of processing you need
    fmt.Println("OUT:", line)
  }
}

func stderrRoutine(stderr io.ReadCloser) {

  defer func() {
    fmt.Println("Closing stderrRoutine")
    stderrDoneChan <- struct{}{}
  }()

  scanner := bufio.NewScanner(stderr)
  for scanner.Scan() {
    line := scanner.Text()
    fmt.Println("ERR:", line)
  }
}
```